RUN behaving weird in Dockerfile
This is snippet from my dockerfile
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/env/ 
COPY var.env /tmp/env/
RUN . /tmp/env/var.env

i.e I want to inject env variables from a file to docker container
but by doing this env variables are not loaded. After container is started if I exec into container and do source /tmp/env/var.env again then env variables are loaded and I can see that with echo $env_name.
any idea?

If you RUN a command that uses the . or export shell built-ins to change the environment, that only lasts until the end of the current RUN command.  You need to use Dockerfile ENV if you want to persistently change the environment for later RUN and CMD instructions.

When working with Docker, each RUN command in a Dockerfile is executed in a new shell session. This means if you set environment variables by sourcing a file with . /tmp/env/var.env in a RUN instruction, those variables will only be available for the duration of that shell session. As soon as the RUN command completes, the shell session ends, and any set environment variables are lost.
To have your environment variables persist and be available when the container starts, you can use the ENV instruction in your Dockerfile. Here's how you might go about it:
You can set Static Environment Variables in Dockerfile: If your environment variables are known in advance, you can set them directly in the Dockerfile using the ENV instruction.
ENV MY_VARIABLE=myValue
ENV ANOTHER_VARIABLE=anotherValue

Or you can using an .env File: If you have an .env file you wish to use for setting environment variables, one approach is to write a script (or an inline shell command in your Dockerfile) that reads the .env file and uses the ENV instruction for each variable. However, this method requires a bit of scripting and goes beyond Docker's standard handling.
For most use cases, directly using the ENV instruction to set environment variables in the Dockerfile is recommended. This ensures that the variables are properly set and available for all commands run during the Docker image build and for the container at startup.
If you absolutely need to load variables from an .env file at container startup, consider adding a step in your startup command or in your entrypoint script (ENTRYPOINT) to source the .env file before starting your main application.

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", ". /tmp/env/var.env && while true; do sleep 1000; done;"]
still i had to manually exec into container and do source /tmp/env/var.env or . /tmp/env/var.env
